# Create calendar appointments with Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, ios, calendar, xamarin.forms, appointment

I need to create calendar appointments in iOS and Android (and somewhen maybe Windows) using Xamarin Forms. I've searched a lot but mainly found articles 2 years ago, referencing outdated plugins I could not get to work anymore. Other postings say that dependency injection is necessary. Is that still the current situation, or are the other plugins in the meantime? I need to create new calendar appointments in users calendar, no need to read the entries. Are there any working samples for Xamarin Forms? I could not get the old ones (e.g. 'Save the Date') to work.
Many thanks!

Comment: You will need either a plugin or the dependency service to be able to access native features.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, yes I know, I just want to avoid using dependency services on my own if there is already a plugin available.

Comment: Did you try [this plugin as well](https://github.com/TheAlmightyBob/Calendars/)?

Comment: @Curiousity, yes, I tried that, but it does not seem to be possible to set reminders there. Just tested again (had some problems on previous test), so if there is no other plugin that might be the one to use.

Comment: It says that _Reminders can be created but not read/edited/removed._ Are you sure you are not missing anything? But there are  considerable set of limitations in this plugin, I see

Comment: @Curiousity, I just tried with the supplied test app and did not find an option there to set a reminder.

Comment: @Curiousity, FYI: It works fine the mentioned plugin. Both creating appointments and adding reminders to the appointment. Thanks!

Comment: Glad if my comments helped in any way and thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: link for create calendar in Xamarin Forms http://michaelridland.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-contest/